# Hitting ORA-01461 when inserting multibyte characters from perl into oracle

Tags: perl, oracle, multibyte, ora-01461

I have a perl script that is inserting records from a text file into our database. Whenever the record has a multibyte character like "RODR_Í_GUEZ". I receive the error ORA-01461, however i'm nowhere near the 4000 characters to switch from varchar2 to long

setting:

```
$ENV{NLS_CHARACTERSET} = 'AL32UTF8';
```

before connecting doesn't seem to help.

Using a java client (SQuirreL SQL) and manually writing the INSERT INTO statement inserts the record just fine, so i'm sure it's not how the database is configured.

Any thoughts?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You probably want to set the NLS_LANG environment variable. For Unix-ish systems, there is a script supplied in $ORACLE_HOME/server/bin called `nls_lang.sh` to output a reasonable value for your system, based on the LANG environment variable.

e.g. for my system (LANG=en_GB.UTF-8) the equivalent Oracle setting is

```
NLS_LANG=ENGLISH_UNITED KINGDOM.AL32UTF8
```

More info: http://forums.oracle.com/forums/thread.jspa?threadID=381531

Sergiusz's post there says practically all you need to know: I'll just add that the Perl DBD::Oracle driver is OCI-based, and the pure-Java JDBC driver isn't, hence they work differently in the same environment.